# My kitten is meowing loudly and constantly

Tags: cats, behavior, vocalizations

Darien, my white Persian cat is 7 months old. I had him vaccinated for rabies when he was 3 months old. He has been dewormed three times, most recently today. He is not neutered.

For the last few days:

1. He's meowing a lot, and very loudly. He used to meow/chirp before, but not always this loud.
2. His appetite is not much. He does eat, but not as much as he used to.
3. His poop is in shape, but it’s not solid.
4. He does not play as much as he used to.

We took him to the vet today. While at the vet, the temperature was fine, and he told us to deworm him, also maybe he's in heat.

I am so worried, as to why he's meowing so loudly and constantly! It's not like we leave him alone, one of my family members is always with him, playing or just beside him. Could you guys help me out, any suggestions?

Comment: Go to another vet. Male cats do not go into heat.

Comment: @AllisonC Yes, I want to. But because of this pandemic, the whole road is in lockdown.

Comment: You listed behavioral changes, appetite changes, and stool changes, all of those are signs of something being wrong. A trip to a vet to treat an ill animal is considered essential in most if not all areas. At a minimum, you MUST call another vet. Your current vet does not seem to be a good choice.

Comment: @AllisonC Yes, I have checked him up with another vet. Dr. told us he is good. I have also answered in a detail. Thank you for you help and suggestion.

Comment: Good. Stick with that vet; any vet who would advise you that your male cat in heat is not a good choice. Glad to hear he's okay!

Answer (score 2):

Alright, so we checked him up again with another vet. After physically examining him, Dr. told us he is good. It might be because summer has arrived he is eating less food (I have checked online and it is true). And about his chirping/meowing, because it is summer, many insects started coming inside the house, which gets him excited! After observing him for some days, I think all his behaviour adds up. He eats like before when it is raining (cold), and he does not meow/chirp a lot when there's no insect. Maybe because this is his first summer experience, he is still getting used to it. I hope this is true, and that he has no other illness.